# The dual of a triangulation of a monotone polygon is a chain

Tags: graph-theory

I am working on the following exercise:

> True or false: Any $y$-monotone polygon allows a triangulation whose dual graph is a chain. (A chain is graph where every vertex has degree at most $2$.)
> NOTE: For this exercise, the dual graph only has a vertex for each triangle and
> no vertex for the outer region.

I think the statement is true. Here is my proof:

We use induction over the number of vertices of the polygon, say $n$.

- I.B.: For $n = 3$ there is nothing to prove.
- I.H.: For every polygonial with $n$ vertices can be triangulated such that the dual of the triangulation is a chain.
- I.S.: $n \rightarrow n+1$: Consider an arbitrary $y$-monotone polygon. Delete the vertex $v$ with the biggest $y-$coordinate (we note that this vertex is unique since the polygon is supposed to be monotone). By I.H. we can triangulate the resulting part of the polygon in such a way that the corresponding dual is a chain. Since the polygon is $y$-monotone the $v$ is an ear of the polygon, so the vertex of the dual associated with the delted region is an end point of the chain.

Could you please tell me if this is correct?